# Minimum Software requirement to connect Xamarin Mac Agent from Windows machine to Mac machine?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, xamarin.ios

I created an iOS app using VS 2017 on Windows 7 pro computerand tried to connect to Mac 10.11 (El Capitan) computer. I am able to see the mac machine from Windows machine using Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Mac Agent.

I have installed no software specific to Xamarin on Mac OS 10.11.

My question is what is the minimum  software that I need to install on Mac machine so I can connect Xamarin Mac Agent from Windows machine to Mac machine?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#Configuring_your_Mac

Comment: Thanks for link Jason. My question is if i am installing VS for Mac do i need.
1.Xamarin iOS SDK.
2.Apple’s Xcode(7+) IDE and                                                                 3.iOS SDK (although the latest stable version from the Mac App Store .  recommended). All i want is mac agent to connect from windows to mac. Is just installing Mono good enough or do i need Visual Studio for Mac and any other software?

Comment: the iOS simulator is part of XCode.  Please edit your question to clarify what you're doing - your title says "build iOS apps" but in your question you say the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect from Visual Studio in Windows to Mac, the minimum software to install on Mac Machine will be only Visual Studio for Mac. Installing it will install the following components for you:

- Visual Studio for Mac IDE
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.Mac
- Xamarin.Android
- Mono runtime

The Visual Studio for Mac will require you to install Xcode in order for iOS development to work. Xcode will be included together with the iOS simulator.

However, latest Xcode (8.3 or 9) required MacOS Sierra (10.12) and above. The latest version of Xamarin.iOS require latest version of Xcode.

In your case, if your Mac is stuck with El capitan OS, you will be only able to update Xcode maximum to v8.2. The compatible Xamarin.iOS version for Xcode 8.2 will be [10.3](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.3/) or [10.4](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.4/). You will need to download these specific version and replace the latest Xamarin.iOS version in your Mac. You can only able to download v10.3 in xamarin.com. You will need to email Xamarin if you want to have v10.4. The download link for v10.3 is [HERE](https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-10.3.1.8.pkg).

After you have configure in your Mac, you will also need to downgrade the Xamarin.iOS version in Windows. You must have matching versions of Xamarin.iOS on both the Windows and Mac machine in order for the Mac Agent to work. The equivalent Xamarin VS version for Xamarin.iOS 10.3 is v4.2. The download link is [HERE](https://dl.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.2.11.msi)

Both the download link is from xamarin.com after you have sign in.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a very detailed answer to my question. I will try it out and let you know if I encounter any problems.  thanks for your help !!!